# XMLHttpRequest responseText not including all the XML

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml

I am new to XML and have been doing some of the tutorials on the w3schools website.

I have been playing with this one tutorial [found here.](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_xml2)
This interacts with the XML [found here.](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/cd_catalog.xml)

A snippet of the XML:

```
<CATALOG>
    <CD>
        <TITLE>Empire Burlesque</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1985</YEAR>
    </CD>
    <CD>
        <TITLE>Hide your heart</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>Bonnie Tyler</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>CBS Records</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1988</YEAR>
    </CD>
```

Now, when I change their source code so the output, instead of being a table, is simply just the responseText received from the xmlhttp object there is a strange occurrence. All TITLE elements are missing for every CD element - all other elements appear. However, when calling the responseXML you can access the TITLE elements.

I changed their source code to this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function loadXMLDoc(url) {
            var xmlhttp;
            var txt, x, xx, i;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else {// code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById('txtCDInfo').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="txtCDInfo">
        <button onclick="loadXMLDoc('cd_catalog.xml')">
            Get CD info</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And I get this output (for space sake I've only included the output that corresponds to the XML snippet included above):

```
Bob Dylan USA Columbia 10.90 1985 Bonnie Tyler UK CBS Records 9.90 1988
```

As can be seen, the TITLE for each CD is missing!

If I haven't explained myself clearly then if you go to the tutorial link and copy the above code into their editor and click "Submit Code" then click the "Get CD Info" button you can see the output more clearly.

What is causing this problem? My brain is frazzled.

Thanks in advance for any help you can give!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not that the title isn't being returned but that your XML contains a tag called "title" which has a special meaning in HTML - namely that it sets the title of the page. If you run that code again, you'll notice that the title of your tab (or browser window, depending on your setup) will change to "Empire Burlesque" which is what the title tag should do in HTML. If you change the  tags to `<title1>` and `</title1>`, you will see the titles show up in your result. Normally you would not want to insert XML directly into an HTML page but rather parse the fields you need. For example, the following code will get the title and artist from the first record in your XML and set the corresponding fields:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <script>
function loadXMLDoc(url)
{
    var xmlhttp;
    var txt,x,xx,i;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById('title').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("TITLE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            document.getElementById('artist').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("ARTIST")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="txtCDInfo">
        <button onclick="loadXMLDoc('cd_catalog.xml')">Get CD info</button>
        <label for="title">Title: </label>
        <div id="title"></div>
        <label for="artist">Artist: </label>
        <div id="artist"></div>
    </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Once you become more comfortable with plain JavaScript, you should consider looking into something like jQuery - it provides lots of functionality to make AJAX calls, parse JSON, XML and manipulate your pages - it takes out a lot of the grunt work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Phil. You're absolutely correct and saved my head from rattling even more! I never realised that responseText was returning the tags, I thought it just returned the data within the tags! I have no reason to print the responseText to the page, I was just experimenting with different situations trying to get comfortable navigating the DOM tree - I just noticed that when I printed on the responseText this strange occurrence happened and I couldn't figure it out - so thank you!!

Comment: No problem, glad that helped. A useful tool to help you debug problems with your documents is the DOM explorer which is included in most major browsers (eg. IE, Firefox, Chrome). You can right click on any part of your page and say "Inspect Element" - this will open a window that will show the current contents of the DOM which can be very helpful in debugging.